JumpList not showing CustomCategory
If I try to specify a CustomCategory when adding JumpTasks to a JumpList, the items won't show up in the list. I am using Winforms.
current code:
private void JumpListUpdate()
{
   JumpList jml = new JumpList();
   jml.ShowRecentCategory = true;
   jml.ShowFrequentCategory = true;

   foreach (string file in Properties.Settings.Default.Recentfiles) {
      JumpTask jmp = new JumpTask();
      jmp.Title = file;
      jmp.CustomCategory = "Levels";
      jml.JumpItems.Add(jmp);
   }
   jml.Apply();
}

If I remove the jmp.CustomCategory = "Levels"; the jump list shows up fine with the file paths, but they're in the "Tasks" category because that's default.

And this is how it looks when the CustomCategory is applied


Which API are you using? If you are using the JumpList class in the namespace System.Windows.Shell, this is for WPF applications, not for WinForms apps.

@jtxkopt-StandWithPalestine That is the API I am using. It's strange though, because it can add the jump tasks to the jumplist just fine. But not when using a custom category.

But to set the JumpList, you should call the JumpList.SetJumpList that takes a System.Windows.Application, that is not compatible with WinForms.

the jml.Apply() method does set the JumpList just fine, as shown in the first screenshot. But it seemingly doesn't apply if the JumpTask as a CustomCategory.

Call the AddToRecentCategory() static method of the JumpList, e.g., JumpList.AddToRecentCategory(jmp); (<- in the loop), otherwise the list may not be updated correctly (the Shell's JumpList is somewhat sticky, so don't be surprised in case you remove the method call and the previous list persists)
